# Setting structure section entry titles dynamically based on the entry level

Tags: templating, entries

I'm trying to set a title for a STRUCTURE entry dynamically based on the structure level within the section hierarchy.

```
{% if entry.level('not 1') %}{ postDate|date('M') }{% else %}{ postDate|date('Y') }{% endif %}
```

I've tried using the above for the title format of my entry type but it only appears to work for setting YYYY for the parent entry and doesn't add the month for child entries.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved the issue by using the following code for my title format

```
{% if object.parent %}{ postDate|date('M') }{% else %}{ postDate|date('Y') }{% endif %}
```